# Application of private/public classes

Tags: java, class, private, public

I have this annoying code:

```
class A{
  private int f=0;
  public void setF(int _f){f=_f;}
  public boolean checkF(int expected){return f==expected;}
}
class B extends A{
  public void setF(int f){[???]}
  public void m(){
    setF(3);
    assert checkF(-3);
    setF(8);
    assert checkF(-8);
  }
}
public class Exercise{
  public static void main(String [] arg){
    new B().m();
  }
}
```

The [???] is where I need to put in an answer.
I'm not sure how to link class B's setF(int f) to class A's setF(int f).
This was my first thought:

```
A an = new A();
an.setF(f);
```

This failed.
I'm stumped, help please.

Comment: I think you want `super.setF(-f);` inside those curly braces; but it's far from clear.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The method `m()` needs to ensure that the opposite of what is passed in to `setF` in `B` comes out in the `checkF` method.  Rather than storing the number as is, as `A` does in `setF`, `B` should override it.  Use `super` to call the overridden `setF` method, to pass the opposite of the number to it.

```
public void setF(int f){
    super.setF(-f);  // Replaces "[???]"
}
```